# Message : Element is not reachable by keyboard

Tags: python, selenium

How can I solve this problem on Python Selenium : Element is not reachable by keyboard ??
I couldn't use the `send_keys("xxx")`

Comment: can you share HTML code and full error stack trace ?

Comment: Message : Element <div id="X14Edit" class="mandatoryFieldStyle xEdit"> is not reachable by keyboard

Comment: Are you launching browser in full mode ? or is it in headless mode ?

Comment: Normally it's full mode PS: I am working with firefox not with chrome browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you to launch screen in full mode :

```
driver.maximize_window()
```

and then use ActionChains like below :

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='instance/header/number' and @datatype='string' and @onkeyup='handleOnChange(this, event);']")).send_keys("XXXX").perform()
```

you will need to import the below for actions chain  :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: I wonder, `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='instance/header/number' and @datatype='string' and @onkeyup='handleOnChange(this, event);']")` this is the web element